# amdgpu not loading

Tags: drivers, kernel, amdgpu, dkms

I ran 2 updates:

```
Upgrade: alsa-ucm-conf:amd64 (1.2.6.3-1ubuntu1.9, 1.2.6.3-1ubuntu1.10), dnsmasq-base:amd64 (2.86-1.1ubuntu0.4, 2.86-1.1ubuntu0.5), libssl3:amd64 (3.0.2-0ubuntu1.12, 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.13), libssl3:i386 (3.0.2-0ubuntu1.12, 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.13), libssl-dev:amd64 (3.0.2-0ubuntu1.12, 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.13), smartmontools:amd64 (7.2-1build2, 7.2-1ubuntu0.1), elisa:amd64 (21.12.3-0ubuntu1, 21.12.3-0ubuntu1.1), openssl:amd64 (3.0.2-0ubuntu1.12, 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.13)
```

And

```
Upgrade: linux-firmware:amd64 (20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu3.24, 20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu3.26)
End-Date: 2024-02-03  04:50:44
```

Now it seems as though amdgpu will not load. I am able to get to command line <kbd>Ctl F2</kbd>. I can launch the GUI with Startx but the display is using motherboard graphics not my AMD GPU.

```
$ sudo lshw -c video:

>*-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Navi 23 [Radeon RX 6600/6600 XT/6600M]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: c1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f01fffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7800000-f78fffff memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display
       description: Display controller
       product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:28 memory:f7400000-f77fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
  *-graphics
       product: EFI VGA
       physical id: 1
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       capabilities: fb
       configuration: depth=32 resolution=1024,768

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy

$ apt show amdgpu
Package: amdgpu
Version: 1:5.7.00.48.50700-1666569.22.04
Priority: optional
Section: metapackages
Maintainer: Advanced Micro Devices (AMD) <slava.grigorev@amd.com>
Installed-Size: 9,216 B
Depends: amdgpu-dkms, amdgpu-lib (= 1:5.7.00.48.50700-1666569.22.04)
Download-Size: 1,688 B
APT-Sources: https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu/23.20.00.48/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
Description: Meta package to install amdgpu components.

$ uname -a
Linux user-user 6.5.0-15-generic #15~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Jan 12 18:54:30 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ dkms status amdgpu
Command 'dkms' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install dkms

$ clinfo
Number of platforms:                             1
  Platform Profile:                              FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Version:                              OpenCL 2.1 AMD-APP (3590.0)
  Platform Name:                                 AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
  Platform Vendor:                               Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
  Platform Extensions:                           cl_khr_icd cl_amd_event_callback 

Platform Name:                                 AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
Number of devices:                               0
```

I installed the ROCm drivers and this command was showing information on the card until I upgraded.

```
$ /opt/rocm/bin/rocm-smi
cat: /sys/module/amdgpu/initstate: No such file or directory
ERROR:root:Driver not initialized (amdgpu not found in modules)
```

Should I try installing the DKMS (`sudo apt install dkms`) to see if that solves anything?

Comment: When installing ROCm, do not install the kernel module to avoid problems. I use ROCm and I never do. Run `sudo apt-get purge <name of the package>` if you did.

Comment: I have another machine with almost the same exact problem that started when I allowed automatic updates. On that one I removed and updated the amdgpu drivers and even installed them without ROCm:  (sudo amdgpu-install -y --accept-eula --usecase=opencl --opencl=rocr,legacy) Still having the same issue with amdgpu not loading/bing found.  I belive its most likely one of the 2 upgrades (linux-firmware probably?) Is there a way to roll back these updates one at a time to test? or do I just need to use an older linux kernel?

Comment: I also have this in my Unattended-upgrades.log file:  pending auto-removals
2024-02-03 15:15:47,436 INFO Package rocm-cmake is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2024-02-03 15:15:47,440 INFO Package rocm-device-libs is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2024-02-03 15:15:47,443 INFO Package rocminfo is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).

Comment: I don't use amdgpu-install. It is too buggy. Just use /etc/apt/preferences.d to prefer the ROCm packages, and install only the packages starting with roc. Use `apt-cache policy packagename` to show the versions of each package, and uninstall and reinstall the ROCm packages if there is a mix between amd and ubuntu packages

Comment: Unless you are compiling your own OS, AMD GPU drivers come out of the box with the kernel and Mesa. Try `modprobe amdgpu` and `dmesg`.

Comment: When checking clinfo and rocminfo I get the same as before.  clinfo:
Number of platforms:   1
  Platform Profile:    FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Version:  OpenCL 2.1 AMD-APP (3602.0)
  Platform Name:  AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
  Platform Vendor:             Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
  Platform Extensions:       cl_khr_icd cl_amd_event_callback 
  Platform Name:                AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
Number of devices:            0
rocminfo:
ROCk module is NOT loaded, possibly no GPU devices

Comment: I use CoreCtrl for more control over my GPUs. I don't really need ROCm. I was just testing it out to see if I could get more control over the AMD GPUs.  My CoreCtrl and GPUs worked just fine with ROCm and with the amdgpu opencl rocr legacy before the update yesterday.  I uninstalled ROCm on one computer and went back to amdgpu opencl but it was still only using the onboard gpu instead of loading the AMD GPU.

Comment: I uninstalled and reinstalled ROCm following this: https://rocm.docs.amd.com/projects/install-on-linux/en/latest/how-to/native-install/ubuntu.html#ubuntu-install  I tried just ROCm but it wouldn't work by itself after installing amdgpu-dkms (sudo apt install amdgpu-dkms). I did install the full ROCm (sudo apt install rocm) instead of just (sudo apt install rocm-hip-sdk) like the instructions say.  However now everything is working so I will leave it be for now.  I will try just the rocm-hip-sdk on the other machine and report back.

Comment: To get OpenCl to work I had to install (sudo apt install rocm) instead of what the instructions say (sudo apt install rocm-hip-sdk).